# Количество элементов массива и получить строку с количеством элементов массива php

Tags: php, массивы, count

Есть массив:

```
array(4) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(12) "Сергей"
  ["surname"]=>
  string(12) "Петров"
  ["city"]=>
  string(12) "Москва"
  ["email"]=>
  string(13) "name@site.com"
}
```

Задача:

Мне нужно узнать количество элементов массива и потом создать переменную в виде строки такого типа...

```
$value = '?, ?, ?, ?';
```

Где знаков вопросов столько же сколько элементов в массиве.

Прошу помощи, так как сам не могу решить данную задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo trim(str_repeat("?, ", count($array)), " ,");`

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!